# Cambiar un json a array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Intento cambiar un json a array para utilizarlo en un state que debo cortar con splice para hacer una paginación pero al parecer el state no se deja cortar. Utilicé debugger y no pasa el array cortado al state items, este sale `undefined`.

En la primera parte está la api: acá intenté pasar el json a array para usarlo en el *App.js*.

En la segunda parte de código está el componente *players*, es el que reproduciría el array de a 10 en 10 elementos, lo uso en *App.js*.

En la tercera parte de código está el *app.js*. Quiero cortar el array pero *items* queda `undefined` y la consola no arroja ningún error, y en la vista la lista no aparece pero la información de otros componentes sí aparece, los cuales no los coloco acá porque creo que no se relaciona.

```
export async function searchTeamPlayers(id = 33){
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`https://v3.football.api-sports.io/players/squads?team=${id}`, {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "x-rapidapi-host": "v3.football.api-sports.io",
                "x-rapidapi-key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                }
            });
            if(!response.ok){
                throw new NetworkError()
            }
            const data = await response.json();

            const players = data.response[0]?.players;
            const arrayPlayers = [];
            for (const i of Object.keys(players)) {
            const name = players[i];
            arrayPlayers.push(name);
            console.log(name);
            }
        return arrayPlayers;

    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
} 

    const Players = (props) => {

    const players = props.players.map((player, index) => {
        return <li className='PlayersTeamLi' key={player.id}>{player.name}</li>
        });

return(
    <div className='DivPlayersTeam'>
        <div className='TitleDivPlayers'><h4>Jugadores</h4></div>
        <div>
            <ul className='PlayersTeamUl'>
                {players}
            </ul>
            <section>
                <button onClick={props.prevHandler}>Prev</button>
                    {props.currentPage}
                <button onClick={props.nextHandler}>Next</button>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}

export default Players;

    const items_per_page = 10;

function App() {

  const [teamPlayers, setTeamPlayers] = useState([]);

  const [items, setItems] = useState([...teamPlayers].splice(0, items_per_page));

useEffect(() => {
    searchTeamPlayers(idTeam)
      .then((data) => setTeamPlayers(data))
      .catch(handleError);
  }, [idTeam]);

function nextHandler() {
    console.log('next');
  }

  function prevHandler() {
    console.log('prev');
  }

return (
 <Players currentPage={0} players={items} nextHandler={nextHandler} prevHandler={prevHandler}></Players>
)}
```

Comment: Podrías agregar que es lo que recibes desde el fetch?

Comment: Claro. disculpa la demora, tuve un inconvniente, pero bueno el fetch segun el console.log arroja el array repitiendo informacion, asi se ve: `[{…}]0: {id: 105971, name: 'G. Bazunu', age: 20, number: null, position: 'Goalkeeper', …}1: {id: 2275, name: 'W. Caballero', age: 41, number: 13, position: 'Goalkeeper', …}2: {id: 40165, 
soccer.js:41 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
soccer.js:41 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
soccer.js:41 (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
soccer.js:41 (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
so [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

Comment: y utilizando debugger en el state teamPlayers el array aparece ordenado asi:                         0: {id: 280, name: 'Alisson', age: 30, number: 1, position: 'Goalkeeper', …}
1: {id: 18812, name: 'Adrián', age: 35, number: 13, position: 'Goalkeeper', …}
2: {id: 138411, name: 'L. Hughes', age: 21, number: null, position: 'Goalkeeper', …}
3: {id: 281, name: 'C. Kelleher', age: 24, number: 62, position: 'Goalkeeper', …}
4: {id: 180316, name: 'H. Davies', age: 19, number: null, position: 'Goalkeeper', …}